# Space bar on keyboards no longer working in LyX

Tags: spacing, lyx, bar

The space bar on ALL my keyboards no longer works in LyX! In order to supply an appropriate space after each word, I can no longer simply press the space bar but have to press SHIFT + SPACE. WHAT has happened and how can I get this back to normal in LyX?

Comment: Have you contacted the lyx helpdesk?

Comment: Have you changed one of your bind files (user dependent bind files are usually at `$HOME/.lyx/bind/`)? Is there a commend like `\bind "space" "…"` with `…` something different than a normal space? You can also [create a list of the used key shortcuts](https://wiki.lyx.org/Tools/LyxBindings) to see what should be.

Comment: Two shots in the dark: exit LyX and remove (but backup!) your user directory; then LyX will generate a new user directory. Second idea: this could be Qt related. Do you see the behavior with other Qt apps on your system?